# Jenkins Builds Failing - Failed to connect to repo

Tags: jenkins

Let me begin by stating this entire process was set up by a former employee. I understand how to use Jenkins and set up new items, but that is about the extent of my knowledge. Everything has been working fine for years, but about a month ago all builds started failing.

When looking at the configuration for each job I see this message:

[image: Jenkins - Failed to connect to repo]

Comparing the console output from successful builds to that of failed builds I also notice some differences. I do not know what they mean though.

A successful build:[image: Success]

Then a few days later the same job failed to build. I do think there were plugin updates or something done in between.

[image: Failed Build]

Can anyone help me solve this to get our development flow back up and working properly? When files are pushed from Bitbucket it automatically kicks off a Jenkins build which pulls the files into our staging server. Since Jenkins is not working correctly I have to manually FTP any new files to our staging server which takes a lot of time.

Comment: authentication failed, check the credentials

Comment: Yeah that is the thing I don't even know how to do that. I don't know where credentials are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the credentials for the Github repository.
Jenkins as extensive documentation on how you can add a credential secret:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

Here is a simple tutorial for it:

[https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/10/jenkins-git-setup/#:~:text=Setup%20Jenkins%20Credentials%20for%20Git&text=To%20add%20a%20credential%2C%20click,Use%20default](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/10/jenkins-git-setup/#:%7E:text=Setup%20Jenkins%20Credentials%20for%20Git&text=To%20add%20a%20credential%2C%20click,Use%20default).

Comment: Thank you @pereira I was able to follow those instructions and get the builds to complete successfully again!